# How to combine two different case sql into 1?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

*This question has asked before in stackoverflow

.[How to use if then statement on sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178193/how-to-use-if-then-statement-on-sql?noredirect=1#comment63789940_38178193)

i have modified and asked again here *

---

1) "`SELECT officer, null, sum(mkt), Sum(Non), sum(ICP), (sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP)) as total From [DB$] group by officer`" <= they are okay. they should be grouped by officer, as every officer have many records

---

2) For the field- mkt, it is not necessarily consisted of value in every record . When mkt consists of value, say 30, it means the officer conduct the field job .Hence, i should count his field hour -Totalmin .

```
  officer mkt Totalmin
   S29    30   50
   S29    60
   S29    70   80
   S29    80
   S55    30   80
   S55    60
   S55    70   80
   S55    80
```

Hence , the result should be :

```
  officer sum(totalmin)
   s29     130
   s55     160
```

[image]

You can imagine here . if the Mkt field consist of numbers ,the total min will be added up and become the min-required .

in the picture ,the min-required output should be `45+40=85` group by officer (staffid-186 )

How to write this sql?

---

And, the problem is i have to combine these two cases in same sql. How can i?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?  I can only see you're using Excel.

Comment: @Raptor i m using Excel .Then import ADO and run the SQL code in VBA

Comment: Can't you do that by adding a `WHERE mkt Is Not Null` clause?

Comment: this would make all field selected by this criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sub-query in select for such task:

```
Sub SQL()
Dim cn As Object: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs As Object: Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim tbl1$, QT, strFile$, strCon$, strSQL$

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'if not active file then specify path!!!

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cn.Open strCon

tbl1 = "[Sheet1$" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address(0, 0) & "]" 'replace sheet1 with required sheet name

strSQL = "SELECT  o.officer ," & _
         "        NULL ," & _
         "        SUM(o.mkt) ," & _
         "        SUM(o.Non) ," & _
         "        SUM(o.ICP) ," & _
         "        ( SELECT    SUM(i.Totalmin) FROM " & tbl1 & " AS i " & _
         "          WHERE i.Mkt > 0 AND i.officer = o.officer) AS TotalMin " & _
         "        FROM    " & tbl1 & " AS o " & _
         "        GROUP BY o.officer"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Workbooks.Add
Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(rs, ActiveSheet.[A1]): QT.Refresh: QT.Delete
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
End Sub
```

I have tested this approach, so it should works fine for you too:

*Source:*

[image]

*Output:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear about your requirement but looks like you need something like this,

```
SELECT officer ,null,sum(mkt) ,Sum(Non),sum(ICP),(sum(mkt)+Sum(Non)+sum(ICP) ) as total, 
    SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true AND Survey = 'CPI' AND Activity = 'FI', Totalmin, 0 )) AS TotalMin 
From [DB$] 
group by officer
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN isnumeric(mkt) = 1 THEN Totalmin ELSE 0 END) AS TotalMin  syntax error

Comment: i m not sure  CASE is it functional in micsoft ADO . But i m sure IIF is usable in ADO . Can it convert to IIF format?

Comment: try changing as - SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = 1, Totalmin, 0 )) AS TotalMin

Comment: no syntax error , but now the whole column become 0 .The output is not successful .

Comment: It works when i change the parameter to  isnumeric(mkt) = true

Comment: How about if i want to add two criteria to the Totalmin field ?  : survey field is "CPI" , Activity field is "FI"

Comment: given that `SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true, Totalmin, 0 ))`

Comment: try adding SUM(IIF( isnumeric(mkt) = true AND survey = 'CPI' AND Activity = 'FI', Totalmin, 0 ))  , check if it support this syntax with AND